# How can I replace the text in a h3 tag on click but without changing other content in it?

Tags: jquery, html, css, onclick

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vwc6ge6m/)

I have a column called “Hand Size” with style of h3 and at the same time there is a hyperlink in the h3 tag so that I can keep the heading “Hand Size” and the hyperlink on the same row.

So for that column, I have a list of size to be selected. Once the user has clicked on the size value, the heading will  be changed with the title value in the anchor tag, i.e. when the user has selected a value (10cm), the heading will be changed from “Hand Size” into “Hand Size : 10 cm”, but at the same time the hyperlink near the title will still appear in the same position.

```
//Hand Size selection
             $(function(){
                $(".hand-value a").click(function(){
                var heading = $(this).attr("title");
                $("#showcase").text(heading);

                var clicked = $(this).parent();
                $(".hand-value").removeClass("active");
                $(clicked).addClass("active");
            });
            })
```

I have created some jQuery for that. Please take a look on the enclosed JSFiddle. But the problem is that when I selected a value, the heading will change to the desired one but the hyperlink will also be replaced.

So how can I replace the heading without replacing the hyperlink in the h3 tag? Thank you so much….

Updates:

-Before Clicking:

[image: Before Clicking]

-Expected Result:

[image: Expected Result]

-Current Result after clicking: (The hyperlink on the right disappeared)

[image]

Comment: Can you please share a fiddle of the whole thing, I read the description few times, but I couldn't quite picture what you want to accomplish (Also, I haven't drank my coffee yet, so the issue could be with me alone) :)

Comment: ＠yavor.vasilev Thank you for your reply, Sorry for the poor English... I have updated some images for illustrating my idea... you can take a look if you have time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your "Hand Size" text into a `span` and change only this. Please try:

```js
$(function(){
 $(".hand-value a").click(function(){
              var heading = $(this).attr("title");
              $("#handSize").text(heading);

              var clicked = $(this).parent();
              $(".hand-value").removeClass("active");
              $(clicked).addClass("active");
             });
})
```

```css
#sizeGuide{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="showcase">
  <span id="handSize">Hand Size</span>
  <a href="google.com" id="sizeGuide">
    Sizing Guide
  </a>
</h3>

<ul>
  <li class="hand-value">
    <a href="#" title="Hand Size : 10 cm">10</a>
  </li>
    <li class="hand-value">
    <a href="#" title="Hand Size : 11 cm">11</a>
  </li>
    <li class="hand-value">
    <a href="#" title="Hand Size : 12 cm">12</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It was a great solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

Your hyperlink is being replaced because its within the H3 tag. Your solution is to either place it outside of the H3 tag or to rewrite it to the H3 tag every time you make a change.

Add this line to your JQuery after you call `$("#showcase").text(heading);`

```
$(" <a href='google.com' id='sizeGuide'>Sizing Guide</a>").appendTo("#showcase");
```

This'll re-insert your anchor to the H3 element every time you change its content.